# Fiddler Wildcard AutoResponse For URL parameters

Tags: fiddler, auto-responder

Is there a way for Fiddler to match an autoresponse for the following URL so it will match ANY wildcard value in the middle of a URL?

http://test.localhost.com/accounts/{*wildcard*}/notes/page/1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a regular expression:

`REGEX:http://test\.localhost\.com/accounts/.*/notes/page/1`

or maybe

`REGEX:http://test\.localhost\.com/accounts/.+/notes/page/1`

if your *wildcard* must be 1 or more characters.

Note: Your question's title mentions "query parameters" but the text of the question seems to concern the "path" component of the URL, since there's no `?` in your sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using AutoResponder, it would be:-

```
[![regex:(?inx)^http://test\.localhost\.com/accounts/.*/.*notes/page/1][1]][1]
```

Use the below case, when host is also[image] not known.

```
regex:(?inx)^https://.+\/accounts/.*/.*/.*
```